# how to get client IP address with node grpc

Tags: grpc-node

Earlier I used below code to get the client IP on `express.js`

```js
req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
req.connection.remoteAddress ||
req.socket.remoteAddress ||
req.connection.socket.remoteAddress
```

would like to know what is the way to get IP of client with grpc node application.
I tried getPeer() which gives always ipv4:127.0.0.1:33944 even when API call is from outside.

Does something equivalent to below go code work?

```js
call.getAttributes().get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR).toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the client IP and port by:

```js
const SayHello = async function (call, callback) {
  const IPandPort = call.getPeer(); // like 127.0.0.1:8080 or just get 127.0.0.1
  console.log(IPandPort);
}
```

See these issues to get more information:

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/pull/1526
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1483